# Sphinx installation error ''invalid option --pgsql"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

My system is MAC OS Big Sure. I wanted to add sphinx to my project but faced problem. When I enter command:

```
 brew install sphinx --pgsql --mysql
```

I got an error:

```
 Error: invalid option: --pgsql
```

Part of my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.2'
     gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.3'
    gem 'thinking-sphinx'
```

And this causes a lot of problems later - I cannot make indexing for my project and make my sphinx search work properly. I am not sure that problem is is exactly in Sphinx, so maybe someone also faced this problem? I already have mysql and postgresql installed.
UPDATE:
Maybe, it would be useful, when I'm trying to index Sphinx - it gives me out this warning:

```
WARNING: index 'post_core': preload: failed to open /Users/user_name/RubymineProjects/app_name/db/sphinx/development/post_core.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Homebrew's version of Sphinx no longer supports configuration to build with PostgreSQL. From a Rails/Thinking Sphinx perspective, that means if your database is PostgreSQL, and you're using SQL-backed indices (`:with => :active_record` in your index definitions), then you can't use Homebrew to install Sphinx.

Instead, your best option is to download the precompiled version of Sphinx 2.2.11 for macOS from Sphinx's website: http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/archive/ … and then you'll have to copy the files within the `bin` folder of your archive into somewhere more permanent (possibly `/usr/local/bin/.`).

Sphinx v3 has issues with PostgreSQL databases, hence why I'm not recommending that in this particular situation.

However, if you're using MySQL for your application database, *or* if you're using real-time indices (`:with => :real_time`), then you could look into using one of the more current Sphinx releases (that also have the advantage of working with MySQL v8+).  Again, you'll need to use the pre-compiled binaries, as Homebrew's version is stuck at v2.2.11. http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/current/